# Removing non printing characters in Excel from data connection

Tags: sql, excel

I have a data connection that returns table from a database into Excel and I wish to count the data in columns but there are some invisible character appearing in the cells.

I am TRIMMING the data in the SQL query as follows;

```
CASE LENGTH(TRIM(DATA.FIELD))
WHEN 0 THEN ''
ELSE TRIM(DATA.FIELD)
END AS "COMPANY NAME"
```

into an Excel table. When I check values in the column with **ISBLANK** I get a **FALSE** returned, and when I check the **LENGTH** I am getting 0.

I have copied the contents of the cells into word and found that the **ASCII** code is 32.

Using `=SUBTOTAL(103,[COMPANY NAME])` to get a count of values but the values are affecting this. Deleting the values from the rows in the column changes the **SUBTOTAL**.

Any help would be much appreciated. I've tried replace code 32 in Excel and that is not removing these cases.

Comment: That is strange. 32 is a SPACE and in excel LEN() should have returned 1.
Is it possible that your when 0 clause above has a space between the single quotes?  You should have an empty string as you expected otherwise. Could you post a sample of the spreadsheet?

Comment: And by the way you could try applying =CLEAN() to your data, it is supposed to remove non printable characters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Excel's CLEAN funstion was not helping me out, I don't think it is designed to remove CODE(32). I have changed my SQL to set "COMPANY NAME" to NULL is the CASE statement returns TRUE and this has fixed my issue in this case. I'm hoping I can use a similar method in some of my other workbooks where I am encountering these invisible characters.